# Is there a way to run D3.js in response to an http request using Node/Express without blocking the server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, d3.js, jsdom

I have used d3.js to generate svg/html on the server using node and jsdom. I have also tested the use of d3 on the server in a web request to generate dynamic svg/html to then use in a template/view (ejs). The problem with this is any significant d3.js code will block the server and will force additional web requests to wait until the svg/html is generated. Is there a way to generate dynamic svg/html in a web request using d3 in nodejs/express without blocking the server?

I've wondered if there is an asynchronous way to write d3, or perhaps a way to use additional workers to generate the svg/html with d3 (and jsdom) in a way that avoids blocking.

Here are some reasons one might want to do this on the server instead of the client: pre-rendering the svg/html and using it in an express template will provide uniform page loading for the user without the "flash" of svg/html being drawn after the page loads like when using d3 in the client. You could also avoid having to send a lot of data to the browser and you could keep d3 code proprietary.

Here is a basic example of what I mean by using d3 in an express route which could block the server for other incoming web requests.

```
app.get("/", async function(req, res) {
    
    // get dynamic data from database based on req.query
    let data = await dbConnection.query(dynamic_sql)

    // create simulated DOM using jsdom. This step will block server.
    const { document } = (new JSDOM(``)).window;

    // use d3 to draw svg. This step will block server.
    let selection = d3.select(document).select("body")
    
    selection.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data).enter()
    .append("circle").attr("r", 5).attr("cx", 10).attr("cy", 10)

    // extract svg string
    let svgString = selection.node().innerHTML

    // pass svgString to template to render page for client
    res.render("/", {svgString: svgString})

}
```

Please let me know if you have any thoughts!

Comment: https://usabilityetc.com/2016/08/how-to-perform-multiple-asynchronous-tasks-with-d3/

Comment: First thing I would recommend is not create a new JSDOM every time. I haven't used JSDOM specifically, but I have used puppeteer, and I had considerable performance gains by reusing a pool of virtual DOMS, and clearing the page between uses rather than generating one every time. I would follow Aydin K's suggestion for d3 asynchronous calls, but if you're super interested in optimisation go for worker threads, but again, operate a pool of workers rather than creating one every time. (they recommend this themselves here: https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html)

Comment: @MichaelBeeson do you have any suggestions on where to learn more about setting up and using a pool of virtual DOMS?

Comment: The easiest improvement I think of is use of `setTimeout`. The user which requested the route will be blocked, but al the others will probably go freely.

Comment: you can add a threadpool of workers using https://www.npmjs.com/package/workerpool, I am not the author but the idea is to offload everything to background thread to avoid blocking the server.

Comment: Add 'cluster' and 'worker-threads' modules to distribute work, maximize utilization of available resources (cores, memory, i/o). Check this article out (https://softwareontheroad.com/nodejs-scalability-issues/). It offers many more node JS performance optimizations, including using the 'cluster' module.

Comment: On your question of using virtual DOM pool -- it is pretty simple. Just maintain a queue of pre-created JSDOM objects and as each request arrives, dispatch one of them to the request handler and attach another handler that waits for a completion event from the request handler. IN the completion event handler, clear the JSDOM and add it back to your queue. When your JSDOM queue is reaching a low threshold size, create a few more JSDOM objects dynamically and add them to the queue to meet demand. When demand falls off, you can remove some JSDOM objects and destroy them to conserve memory.